# Overwrite images when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

I'm developing a site for buying clothes. I need to create a product that, on clicking in the pocket image, change immediately in the preview. How can I do that? I am using Angular 2

[Example of how I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLt5f.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img [src]="imageUrl">
<button (click)="imageUrl='http://example.com/path/image1.png'">Image 1</button>
<button (click)="imageUrl='http://example.com/path/image2.png'">Image 2</button>
<button (click)="imageUrl='http://example.com/path/image3.png'">Image 3</button>
```

```
export class MyComponent {
  imageUrl:string;
}
```

Comment: I just changed the double quotes and it worked perfectly:

<button (click)="imageUrl='http://example.com/path/image1.png'">Image 1</button>

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that. Thanks for the hint